# How to learn math?

Tags: self-learning, learning

I am 19 years old and I'm computer programmer and Software Engendering college Student, And I am smart (mean: I am not stupid) and know programing better than other, I think math is like programming.

**I can program (Algorithm) math formula with C++ or even PHP**. But I can't understand the mathematics by my brain. and I am going to leave collage for this reason(can't understand math).

I think the reason that I can't understand math is from my elementary School when I was lazy.

Unfortunately after that I didn't try to make my mathematics better , And maybe its not bad to know that I became best programmer in a big competition.

**OK My questions:**

1-Can I learn math as well (I start late)?

2-What steps and exercise do you suggest?

3-How to learn?

Comment: Good luck!  You can do it!

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Give me suggestion please. thanks bro

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE And please vote up, because the question with up vote get better answer

Comment: @LASH Don't beg for upvotes. You will get upvotes if users think your question deserves them.

Comment: Good questions get up-votes!

Comment: @LASH: you need to learn to study. To be disciplined and to train yourself. It looks like you have been able to go ahead by hacking your way through, because you have a talent for programming. But eventually you were going to hit the ceiling. Now the time to work hard has come.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My answer to number 1 is a resounding ***YES!*** Of course, you can *always* learn math.

However, you won't like my other advice: don't leave college. Your desire to leave it is a remnant of the same laziness that caused you to learn mathematics badly in elementary school.

In college, a lot of mathematics starts over. You don't really need a lot of mathematical knowledge from elementary school. In fact, I would argue that you don't really learn math in elementary school. You learn arithmetic. The stuff you are learning at high school is the zero level maths at which you should start. Therefore, my advice is:

1. Stay in college
2. Do *a lot* of exercises in mathematics. Your professor is probably following a textbook which probably has some exercises at the end of each chapter. When your professors covers a subject, solve the exercises at the end. Every one of them. Work on each for at least an hour before giving up. If you cannot solve something, go ask your professor (or someone) for help. If he's any good, he will be happy to help.

If you do enough exercises and are of at least average intelligence, you will catch up to your peers in no time. Trust me, all of them got almost the same shock as you.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt learn math from elementry and continued to high school and collage.... . Thanks I want to do the things that you said. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You're only 19, so yes you can definitely learn math at your age.

Find out what strands of math are giving you trouble and go back to the basics for that particular strand of math.

Doing lots and lots of exercises is a sure way to learn/reinforce a concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot I love to learn math